# Setup subdomain in Apache server ubuntu 16.04 lts

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, dns, subdomain

How can I setup a subdomain in Apache on an ubuntu server.

My apache.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.hello.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:81>
        ServerName bye.hello.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/other
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Now my access is by IP: 10.20.20.34:80 (www.hello.com) and 10.20.20.34:81 (bye.hello.com). The 80 port works great, but I can't set up a subdomain for 81 port.

We don't need public access, everything is over the intranet. We modified DNS record in our router.

**IMPORTANT**: I have to keep both access: 10.20.20.34:81 and bye.hello.com

Here is a summary of what happens:

- 10.20.20.34:80 - OK.
- 10.20.20.34:81 - OK.
- www.hello.com - OK.
- bye.hello.com - FAIL, show me www.hello.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add a [listen directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mpm_common.html#listen) to your `/etc/apache2/ports.conf`. In that file you will see:

```
Listen 80
```

Add a second line underneath:

```
Listen 80
Listen 81
```

Then restart Apache:

```
apache2ctl restart
```

Otherwise, I do not see any problems with your Virtual Host settings.

**Update**

Apache won't do this for you through the DNS.  You can read [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/74362/how-to-use-dns-hostnames-or-other-ways-to-resolve-to-a-specific-ipport) to learn more.  The best thing for you to do is change the second Virtual Host directive to:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName bye.hello.com
```

And it should work fine. There is no advantage to using two ports.  If you have an architectural limitation, then the link above had a few advanced solutions.

Comment: I had this.
10.20.20.34:80 - OK.
10.20.20.34:81 - OK.
www.hello.com - OK.
bye.hello.com - FAIL, show me www.hello.com

Comment: So what happens when you try bye.hello.com? 404? Have you checked /var/log/apache2/error.log?

Comment: @JuanPabloLarrea   So glad to hear it!